# return RedirectToAction() based on user role inside a switch statement that is returning Views()'s

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

After a successful login by a user, I want the page to redirect to suitable page in accordance to the user role. I have got some code working which allows me to retrieve and check user role from the login credentials, however the switch statement will not allow me to use an if-else statement.

It wants me to return a View(), but I am always redirected to the `Home/Index` view. Here's my code:

```
        switch (result)
        {

            case SignInStatus.Success:
                MigrateShoppingCart(model.Email);
                //returnURL needs to be decoded
                string decodedUrl = "";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                    decodedUrl = Server.UrlDecode(returnUrl);

                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(decodedUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(decodedUrl);
                }

                string id = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email).Id;
                IList<string> roleNames = UserManager.GetRoles(id);

                if (roleNames.Contains("Admin"))
                {
                    RedirectToAction("Index", "Category");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                return View();
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I am always redirected to the `Home/Index` view even when the user has "Admin" role.

Comment: Can you share rolenames value before if?

Comment: rolenames value contained "Admin" when debugging and logging as the admin. See my answer below, it was a small problem in my code. I should have used the `return` keyword in the first if-case body. Then it allowed me to remove the `return View()` line code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a small error in my code since I did not use the `return` word in the first if-case. Change this code:

```
if (roleNames.Contains("Admin"))
{
    RedirectToAction("Index", "Category");
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
return View();
case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
return View("Lockout");
```

To this:

```
if (roleNames.Contains("Admin"))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Category");
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
return View("Lockout");
```

Notice I was also able to remove the `return view()` code.